# Okay to use the hash DOM node property?

Tags: html, javascript, browser-support

Would you advise against *reading* and using the `hash` DOM node property? (Do you think it might be deprecated and removed in the future?)

What is it? For a link `<a href='http://server/folder/page#the-hash'>`, the value of the hash property is `#the-hash`. It seems to be present in all browsers, see [the JavaScript Bible page 603](http://goo.gl/OF16Q), and I've tested Safari, Chrome, FF and IE and Opera.

**Background:** I use jQuery, but in IE 7 this: `$(elem).attr('href');` doesn't return the `href` attribute, but rather the `href` prefixed with server address and the path to the page. Example: if the `href` is `#the-hash` then `attr` returns `http://server/folder/page#the-hash` in IE 7. 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRaXg/) is a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Are you planning on etching your script in stone or something?

Comment: I don't think it's going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: @cHao - Would that be a bash script? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stay away from every feature, API, etc that might possibly be deprecated sometime in the distant future, you'll never get anything done.  They could deprecate `alert` tomorrow, or `for`...`in` (far more likely, but eh.  that's beside the point.)

Worry about what's deprecated *now*.  And `location.hash` is not.  It's a full-fledged member of the HTML5 DOM, and will be for the foreseeable future.  If it ever does end up deprecated, it'll probably still be supported for ages after, as a "living standard" (which is what HTML has allegedly become) makes things exceedingly hard to deprecate and/or remove.

Either way, if you want to change it later, you can.